# Rails model design for user specific result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I currently have two Rails models as follows:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_interests
end

class JobInterest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :applicant

  enum status: { pending: 0, accepted: 1, rejected: 2, cancelled: 3 }
end
```

I am trying to achieve that for a specific applicant (user) I can serve a list of Jobs. Each Job should be associated with one or zero JobInterest instances (for that specific user).

I've thought of multiple ways to achieve this, but all seem a bit cumbersome.

**Possible solution 1:**

Basically use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, e.g.

`Job.includes(:job_interests).where(job_interests: { applicant_id: [current_applicant.id, nil] }).all`

This results in a job list, each job having a property called `job_interests` which should have one item or none. One if the applicant has expressed interested, and none if the applicant hasn't done so.

Drawback: this doesn't seem like to the most straightforward approach.

**Possible solution 2:**

When a Job is created, automatically create JobInterests for all applicants belonging to this job. Given a lot of applications, this doesn't scale well and requires a lot of extra rows.
On the other hand, one can now get the Job list by calling

`JobInterest.where(applicant_id: current_applicant.id).all`
, which seems much cleaner than the previous approach.

Would you pick any of these approaches, or suggest another approach I haven't thought of.

Comment: So you want a list of jobs that have the same job interests (at least one) as the applicant?

Comment: @BillyFerguson not exactly, a JobInterest instance here basically means that someone is interested in a certain Job (ad), basically it's a response to  Job ad. So in my client (app) I want to basically display a list that has al jobs the applicant hasn't applied to, mixed with jobs he has already applied to

Comment: So jobs that have the same interests as a job they already applied to?

Comment: @BillyFerguson no not quite. Say I'm an applicant and I view a Job in my app. Then it is marked that he is interested in the Job by creating a JobInterest instance for that specific job. E.g. a Job instance can have many JobInterests, one for each applicant.

Answer (score 1):

So based on my comments in your question I think its just a simple `has_many :through` association. A `User` has many job interests and a `Job` has many interested `Users`.

```
class JobInterest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :Job
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobinterests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :jobinterests
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobinterests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :jobinterests
end
```

This way you can simply add jobs to job interests when you view them, and remove them from the list when the user opts out of the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are you suggesting that when I present a list of Jobs, I then create JobInterests for those Jobs that haven't got a JobInterest for that user yet?

Comment: Yeah, or present a list of jobs and allow an applicant to `favorite` or specify an interest in the job. So don't add them ALL to the interests. Only the ones that he views or the ones that he clicks favorite on. I'll leave the implementation up to you. But does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, so present a list and when the user enters the detail view create the JobInterest. Thanks for your ideas, I'll await other answers before I mark something as being 'the' answer.

Comment: Upvote for the points if you like! I think that's the most straight forward approach for what you're getting after though.

Comment: one more consideration is that in my app in the list of all jobs I do want to show somehow that the job is already 'favorited' (to use your vocab). But you could probably just look at the JobInterests for a job and pick the one for the current user (e.g. job.job_interests.where(user_id: 1).first))

Comment: No that's easy, I did something similar to that. For each Job partial you just do `@job in User.jobs` and if the `job` is in the `User.jobs` collection you add a star or w/e with CSS. It is wayyyy more performant to stay within the things that you have prebuilt indexed lists over random where clauses. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that achieves the same. Performance depends on the amount of JobInterests I would guess. If that would be a huge number per job the `where` clause will probably more performant.

Comment: One thing that isn't possible in this approach is that, say you want to list favorited jobs first, then list all other jobs. Then you would need some kind of query like my solution #1 though.

Comment: You could do it in two parts. `User.jobs` then `Jobs.where.not(id: User.jobs)`